# What happens when you override an arrow function with a named function?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, callback, bind, es6-class

I have a code like the following:

```
class ClickModule {
   constructor() {
      this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
   }

   handleClick = (evt) => {}
}

class ImageModule extends ClickModule {
   handleClick(evt) {
      //some logic that never gets called
   }
}
```

handleClick is a function used as a callback.
I know you cannot bind an arrow function, but as it is being overridden as a class method, why is it not working?

The fix was to declare the initial handleClick as

```
handleClick(evt) {}
```

But I don't understand quite well what was producing that the handleClick in ImageModule was never called.

Thanks

I tested it on this codePen https://codepen.io/mpfrancog/pen/rNZREdx

Comment: The method in the second declaration is declared on the prototype, but the arrow function (which can't be bound but can be declared in the constructor `constructor() { this.handleClick = (evt) => {}; }`) isn't. So *either* make it a class property with an anonymous arrow function assigned to it, *or* make it a method, then override it using the same means.

Comment: @Unmitigated I added a codepen

Comment: javascript looks for properties before looking at the prototype, so the parent property is shadowing the child prototype method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `handleClick` on `ImageModule` isn't being used at all, because `ClickModule`'s class *property* (not method) is assigned to the *instance* at construction time, so it takes precedence over the `handleClick` on the prototype the instance gets from `ImageModule.prototype`.

Here's what happens when you do `new ImageModule`:

1. The (automatically-generated) `ImageModule` constructor is called.
2. It calls `ClickModule`'s constructor.
3. Just before `ClickModule`'s constructor is called, an instance is created using `ImageModule.prototype` as its prototype. `ImageModule.prototype` has `handleClick` from `ImageModule`, so for this brief moment, the instance would inherit that method. But...
4. The code in `ClickModule`'s constructor is called.

   - The first thing in that constructor is the class property you've defined here:

     ```js
     handleClick = (evt) => {}
     ```

     When the class was built, that code was put in the constructor as though the constructor started with this:

     ```js
     Object.defineProperty(this, "handleClick", {
          "value": (evt) => {},
          "writable": true,
          "enumerable": true,
          "configurable": true
     });
     ```

     That is, it puts the property on the instance (replacing any property that was there, but there wasn't in this case), so the property the instance inherits from its prototype will not be used.
   - The constructor's code continues with the `bind` call, using the *instance* (not prototype) property and then writing to it. The `bind` call doesn't have any effect (in this case), since it doesn't bind any arguments and attempts to bind the `this` value that the arrow function already closes over.

So `ImageModule`'s `handleClick` isn't used at all.

If you want to have a method that subclasses can override, define a *method*, not a class property:

```
class ClickModule {
    constructor() {
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick(evt) {
        // ...presumably some code here...
    }
}

class ImageModule extends ClickModule {
    handleClick(evt) {
        // ...some logic that now _will_ get called...
    }
}
```

That way, the `bind` call in `ClickModule` is working with the `handleClick` on the instance's prototype, which is the one from `ImageModule`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I was having trouble understanding this step by step.